# Why array comparison isn't working? (GAS)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison

The code below used to work. Now, when comparing two arrays, even though there is a difference, as highlighted below, the code says that there is a duplicate.
I've tried it using .join() as well, but I keep getting the same result.

Script:

```
function SaveEditedEntry() {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(3000);
  if (lock.hasLock()) {
    var sourceSheet = 'Entries';
    var destinationSheet = 'Database';
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
    var LastRowSource = sheet.getLastRow();
    //var LastColumnSource = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var entryValues = sheet.getRange(7, 1, LastRowSource, 16).getValues();
    var dbSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
    var entryDataPushed = [];
    var dbData = dbSheet.getRange(2, 1, dbSheet.getLastRow(), 16).getValues();
    var dbDataPushed = [];
    //var dbDataPushed = new Array();
    var company = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
    var period = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
    var entryID = sheet.getRange("J5").getValue();
    var timeStamp = new Date();
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    if (company == '') {
      Browser.msgBox('Make sure that you have chosen a valid company.');
      return;
    }
    if (period == '') {
      Browser.msgBox('Please, make sure that you have chosen a valid period.');
      return;
    }
    var emptyRow = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < entryValues.length; i++) {
      if (entryValues[i][0] != '') {
        emptyRow = i + 1;
      }
      if (emptyRow < 1) {
        Browser.msgBox('Please, make sure that you have entered a transaction.');
        return;
      }
      if (entryValues[i][0] != '') {
        entryDataPushed.push(entryValues[i]);
      }
    }

    for (var n = 0; n < dbData.length; n++) {
      if (dbData[n][1] != '' && dbData[n][0] == company && dbData[n][14] == period) {
        dbDataPushed.push(dbData[n]);
      }
    }

    var duplicate = false;
    loop1:
    for (var x = 0; x < entryValues.length; x++) {
      loop2:
      for (var j = 0; j < dbDataPushed.length; j++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(entryValues[x]) == JSON.stringify(dbDataPushed[j])) {
          duplicate = true;
          break loop1;
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.log("EntryDataPushed: " + entryDataPushed);
    Logger.log("dbDataPushed: " + dbDataPushed);

    if (duplicate == true) {
      Browser.msgBox('No change has been made.');
      return;
```

This is the logs print:
[image]

Could anyone point me to the right direction on getting this solved?

Thank you!
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were comparing `entryValues` vs `dbDataPushed` but is logging `entryDataPushed` and `dbDataPushed`. Is this expected?

Anyways, since you are logging the variables, I assume the variables logged are the ones you need to compare.

Convert them into JSON string by wrapping the variables with `JSON.stringify()`. I use this all the time when I encounter an issue similar to yours right now.

```
var duplicate = false;
if (JSON.stringify(entryDataPushed) == JSON.stringify(dbDataPushed)) {
  duplicate = true;
}
```

**Output:**
[image: output]

See resource below for other ways to properly compare arrays if the above code doesn't work.

**Resources:**

- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [StackOverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: I've tried it, but it shows the same result = duplicate, even though one value is different. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Hi @AntonioSantos, Sorry that I forgot that you actually traverse per element of both arrays. I have updated the answer and try that instead.

Comment: Hi, @NaziA! Still the same. I'll share the rest of the code to see if there's any stealth flaw I may have missed.

Comment: If that won't be a hassle, that would be better. Thanks @AntonioSantos. If you can, kindly provide the array values to so that I can test it on my side, it would be much better.

Comment: Here's a copy of the spreadsheet with the dummy data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S0KOStgG8kM8py_WaudAdcXnSFpertaWwfej8P-lfC4/edit?usp=sharing Appreciate your time!

Comment: It is working on my side @AntonioSantos when using the updated answer.

I'll add the proof to the answer where it shows that a change has been made

Comment: There may be an error with the loops on my side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @AntonioSantos, You were comparing `entryValues` vs `dbDataPushed` but is logging `entryDataPushed` and `dbDataPushed`. Anyways, since you are logging `entryDataPushed` and `dbDataPushed`, I assume the variables logged are the ones you need to compare. It might have been the reason but didn't check since the condition is already working. Glad to be of help. Good luck

Comment: Your attention and will to help are incredible. Thanks a million! Problem solved!